# updateShapeProperties complaining about missing fields property

Tags: google-slides-api

Details

- OS: Manjaro Linux
- Node.js version: 10
- npm version: 6
- `googleapis` version: 51.0.0

Steps to reproduce

1. We are sending a google slide API request with updateShapeProperties:

```json
        "updateShapeProperties": {
            "objectId": objectId,
            "shapeProperties": {
                "shapeBackgroundFill": {
                    "solidFill": {
                        "color": {
                            "rgbColor": {
                                "red": r,
                                "green": g,
                                "blue": b
                            }
                        },
                        "alpha": 1
                    }
                },
                "outline": {
                    "outlineFill": {
                        "solidFill": {
                            "color": {
                                "rgbColor": {
                                    "red": 0,
                                    "green": 0,
                                    "blue": 0
                                }
                            },
                            "alpha": 0.1
                        }
                    },
                },
                "contentAlignment": "MIDDLE"
            },
            "fields": "*"
        }
```

where `objectId` comes from one of any `pageElement` we get from `slide.pageElements`

2. We get a 400 response that states:

```
message: ""Invalid requests[2].updateShapeProperties: At least one field must be listed in 'fields'. (Use '*' to indicate all fields.)
```

This somehow used to work the past few months, and was wondering why it suddenly doesn't work right now. Did we have any changes or updates on the `updateShapeProperties` API?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `[2]` of `Invalid requests[2].updateShapeProperties` is the request body in your question. When I tested your request body, I could replicate your situation. The error message is `At least one field must be listed in 'fields'. (Use '*' to indicate all fields.)`. When I tested `"fields": ""`, I got the same error message. From this situation, I thought that it might be a bug.

When I searched this situation at the Google issue tracker, I found it. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174129493)

So as the current workaround, in order to avoid this error, in your request body, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
"fields": "*"
```

#### To:

```
"fields": "shapeBackgroundFill,outline,contentAlignment"
```